# Flutter Desktop: How to disable "disabled" mouse-cursor on button-hover?

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop

By default, on Desktop, btns in flutter change the Mouse Cursor when they are disabled:

[image]

We'd like to disable this behavior, or replace with a different cursor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To override the default *disabledMouseCursor* for `ElevatedButton`, `TextButton`  or `OutlinedButton`, one could write:

```dart
        ElevatedButton(
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            disabledMouseCursor: SystemMouseCursors.basic,
          ),
          // ...
        )
```

See [ButtonStyle class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ButtonStyle-class.html) for more information.

Comment: That's a very handy constuctor, and of course, `ButtonStyle.mouseCursor` under the hood. Cheers!